# How to create a combination in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like following

[image]

[image]

Now I want create a combination table like following

[image]

Now my question is that how create Table c from Table A and table B without using any loop

Comment: What is the relationship between both? Why do you need a new table? If the name of `A` changes, must it be updated in `C` too?

Comment: Looks like a cross join could help. But you need to provide information on how the tables are related?

Comment: There is no relation between Table A and table B

Comment: Do you need a table or just the results?

Comment: @PatrickHofman and Shree.pat18: You don't need a relationship when doing a cartesian join. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A simple cartesian/cross join should do what you want:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A_Id, B_Id) AS C_Id,
    A_Name,
    B_Name
FROM
    [Table A],
    [Table B]
```

The following syntax is equivalent:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    [Table A] CROSS JOIN [Table B]
```